# Select with all parameters

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Let's say I have 5 parameters to a method and those are columns in say, 3 different tables. And the method callers can pass null to all the parameters. Part of my Linq below

```
public Customer GetCustomer(int id, DateTime? dob, string FName, string MI, string LName)
{
    query = (from customer in CustomerDb.customers
            join 
            ,...
            where cpn.FirstName == FName && cpn.LName == LName
            ..
            select customer);
}
```

Now if they only provide a FName, I want my where clause to only contain the FName attribute. And is if-else or switch case the only way to accomplish this? I can't put everything in the query with an and because if they only supply a FName, I will look for nulls in dob, id, MI and LName. And they could pass null to all values (0 in case of int) too which means I need to return everything in the DB not an AND of nulls.

Comment: Anything stopping you from adding the where statements onto the `IQueryable` after you setup the query?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply extend your where to account for default values:

```
where (FName == null || cpn.FirstName == FName) && (LName == null || cpn.LName == LName)
```

It will complicate the where a little but I see no reason why it should fail or perform badly.

Comment: The only problem with this is my (not nullable) integer fields. If they pass a zero, I don't want to query with zero. I don't even want that field in my query.

Comment: If your integer is not nullable, then how can you distinguish if you need to search for 0 or not?

Is 0 a special meaning for the id that says "don't search"? If that is the case you can use the same construct (id == 0 || cpn.ID == id)

Answer (score 1):

> I need to return everything in the DB not an AND of nulls.

Using Lambda:

```
public Customer GetCustomer(int? id, DateTime? dob, string fName, 
  string mi, string lName)
{    
  IQuerable<Customer> query = CustomerDb.customers;

  if (id.HasValue)
  {
    query = query.Where(c => c.id == id.Value)
  }
  else
  {
    query = query.Where(c => c.id == null)      
  }

  if (dob.HasValue)  
  {
    query = query.Where(c => c.Dob == dob.Value)
  }
  else
  {
    query = query.Where(c => c.Dob == null)      
  }

  if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(fName))
  {
    query = query.Where(c => c.FName == fName)
  }
  else
  {
    query = query.Where(c => c.Fname == null)      
  }

  // repeat for mi, lName

  var result = query.FirstOrDefault();

  return result;
}
```

If you don't want to filter on no value passed, simply remove the else statement(s) of your choice.